# Receiving a Discord.Net 2000 character limit warning when I am not sending a message

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

I have a command below that should send a random word into the context channel.

```cs
[Command("word"), Summary("Chooses a random English word.")]
public async Task RandomWord(string culture = "uk")
{
    if (culture == "uk")
    {
        // Reads all the lines of the word list.  
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Resources.english_uk_wordlist);

        // Chooses a random line and its word.
        var word = allLines[_random.Next(0, allLines.Length - 1)];

        // Sends random chosen word to channel.
        await ReplyAsync(word.First().ToString().ToUpper() + word.Substring(1));
    }
}
```

However, I receive and error saying that I have exceeded Discord's 2000 character message limit on this line.

```cs
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Resources.english_uk_wordlist);
```

This is strange to me because reading these lines should have nothing to do with Discord.Net or Discord's API. It is important to note that when I put this text file outside of my `Resources.resx`, it works fine.

I have also tried using `StreamReader` which results in the same problem. If it helps, the value of `allLines.Length` is 854236.

Thanks.

Comment: Answers belong in *answers*, not edited into the question. Questions have been successfully answered when one of the answers is *accepted*, not be editing the title of the question. The answer you edited into the question is still available in the edit history, if you wish to retrieve the content and use it to write an answer.

Comment: Please see the help topics [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: My bad, I did not see your comments. I will make the necessary changes in due course.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I think your comments are obsolete, since OP answered the question in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Resources.english_wordlist_uk` is a string, not a path.

**Code A**

```
var location = Resources.english_wordlist_uk;
var readText = File.ReadAllLines(location);
```

The above code reads `Resources.english_wordlist_uk` and uses its contents as a path. It does not recognize the file itself as a path.

**Code B**

```
var location = Resources.english_wordlist_uk;
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(location))
{
    var readText = sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

This code reads the content of `Resources.english_wordlist_uk` as if it were a string, resulting in `readText` being the entire contents of the file.

**Explanation**

The reason I received a 2000 character limit error is because of **Code A**. Since the content of `Resources.english_uk_wordlist`is not a path, the error message was something along the lines of: "Specified path (content of the file) does not exist."

Since my command handler sends the error message in the channel, and the error message is hundreds of thousands of characters, Discord could not send the error message. **Code B** is a clean solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi, please mark your answer as answer if it answers your question 

Answer (score 1):

If you can tell the value of `allLines.Length`, then `ReadAllLines` must have been successful. I think that the `await` is confusing the debugger.

Set a breakpoint on the line with `await`. Compile and run in Debug mode. Then Discord will not be affected. It will also allow you to see what's inside the `word` variable.

Note that the upper limit for [Random.Next(min, max)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8) is exclusive. So it should probably be `_random.Next(0, allLines.Length)`, unless the last line is empty.

Comment: I suspected that too; however, that does not seem to be the case. If I comment out everything but `var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Resources.english_uk_wordlist);`, I still receive the 2000 char limit error. In debugger, the value of `allLines` and `word` seems to be `null`.

Comment: @MatthewTrip: if the code isn't there, there are a few options: a) you're debugging an out of date assembly, b) you're using an out of date pdb, c) you're debugging with a assembly / pdb mismatch (doing release builds can cause this), d) your IDE is messed up and needs to be restarted. e) you're not using the `File` from `System.IO`. In any case; you where right that `File.ReadAllLines(Resources.english_uk_wordlist)` has nothing to do with `discord`; so that line is not causing the error.

Comment: @Stefan I have solved my issue :) Please see the edit in the post.